# Installed Kali linux in VMware, Wireless adapter not detected

Tags: linux, networking, kali-linux, vmware-player

> Hi all, I have been trying since long time to establish wireless connection in kali guest OS on Windows 10 host. 
>   I have purchased TP-LINK TLWN722N version 2 RealTeck chipset, 
>   As i have been suggested to use this for kali. which is plug and play.
>   Have a look at VM settings below attached with the command outputs for ifconfig, iwconfig, lsusb

https://i.stack.imgur.com/da6oq.jpg

Please let me know the solution. Had been reasearching online quite 2-3 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. **Wireless card not connected** with Virtual Machine

   If this is the case then you can fix issue by connecting wireless card to virtual machine.

   Go to VM > Removable devices > (wireless card name/number) > **Connect (Disconnect from Host)**
2. **Compatible driver not found** (very less chance for your case but maybe)

   In this case, [Download Driver from TP-Link](http://www.tp-link.com/us/download/TL-WN722N.html#Driver) website and install it.

**Driver Installation Guide:**

1. Unzip drivers zip file in home folder
2. Open Terminal and run these commands:

   ```
   cd ZippedFolderName
   sudo apt-get install gcc build-essential linux-headers-generic linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
   make
   sudo make install
   modprobe rtl8188e
   ```

**TIP:** Try following commands in terminal:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: Yes i get the the error. Driver was not installed successfully

Comment: download driver from above link and follow above guideline (added in answer)

Comment: Thank you very much.. now im able to see wireless option.. but I'm not able to connect to internet.. though i can ping gateway. It's reachable. But cant brows anything

Comment: Please let me know if you need any command outputs..

Comment: well, that's strange. First of all, make sure you have installed right driver because that device is available in 2 different version (1.0 and 2.0). If so then attach images for ping request + these commands (ifconfig, iwconfig, lsusb). Let see, how can I help more

Comment: I am using V2.0 only and have installed right driver as you said above. Though i got some errors while driver installation. I sort a way out of it for smooth installation. Checkout the command outputs in here. http://imgur.com/a/zZLff

Comment: Did you get anything? I'm waiting for your answer..

Comment: It's hard to guider further because there can be a very tiny mistake or a bug. So, try to reset your network manager, and try another browser. If none of this work then I would suggest to re-install kali and get latest update. Hopefully, this will work!